# Rheumatoid arthritis and hormones

Tags: autoimmune-disease, arthritis

If rheumatoid arthritis symptoms improve during pregnancy, why women are not treated with hormones?

Comment: Welcome to health SE :-). For future questions, it would be great if you included some of your own research into the question. Thanks!

Comment: Pregnancy is a state of alerted immunity, primarily so that the mother does not reject the developing fetus. A side effect of this is that some people with autoimmune diseases may improve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Women are actually treated with hormones, just ones that aren't estrogen/progesterone/ect..

People with severe RA are treated with glucocorticoids in order to decrease T and B cell proliferation that further damage to the synovial joints. These hormones have long term health impacts (such as Cushing's disease) and should be used as a last ditch effort.

Hormones such as progesterone and estrogen, which are at elevated levels during pregnancy, may decrease T cell  and B cell proliferation to an extent, but they are not as efficacious as glucocorticoids. Furthermore, estrogen and progesterone are related to many other autoimmune diseases: http://www.medscape.com/viewarticle/775536_5

Here is information regarding estrogen's role in decreasing T cell proliferation: https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/8955504

*Note: women who are young enough to conceive without medical assistance may still have a thymus. The reduction in thymus activity by estrogen may decrease RA symptoms. However, older women do not have a thymus and will not experience any effects like this from estrogen.